# Converting a "DBML" file to a "SQL database file"

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the DBML file of a database and would like to generate an SQL database file from this file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a method on the Data Context called CreateDatabase() that you could use.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.createdatabase.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CLI tool.

```
dbml2sql schema.dbml -o schema.sql
```

https://www.dbml.org/cli/#convert-a-dbml-file-to-sql

Comment: The `dbml2sql` CLI tool can now be found at https://dbml.dbdiagram.io/cli/

Answer (score 1):

I know of no available utilities that do that, and it's a bit much to do for a SO answer.

But, for the most part, it's not that big a deal.  The DBML file is written in XML; it should be easy to read via Linq-to-xml.  Then just split out the SQL commands for the values in the xml into a script file.  Then run the script.  (It also could be done with a XSLT transformation)

```
<Table Name="dbo.Person" Member="Persons">
```

becomes

```
 CREATE TABLE Persons (
```

and

```
  <Column Name="PersonID" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY"
          IsPrimaryKey="true" IsDbGenerated="true" CanBeNull="false">
  </Column>

  <Column Name="AddressID" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL" 
          CanBeNull="false"></Column>
```

becomes:

```
 PersonID Int NOT NULL,
 AddressID int NOT NULL,
```

and so on.